# Function to check if string is a valid password using regex

Tags: r, regex

I'm not sure how to implement all these requirements in regex (in R).

The string is a valid password if:

- 8 characters minimum
- has at least 1 lowercase letter
- has at least 1 uppercase letter
- has at least 1 number
- has at least 1 of the special characters - `!@#$%^&*`
- CANNOT contain pattern `hello` OR `123`

Nothing seems to be working if I try to implement all these rules, so any advice/help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide some examples of "Nothing seems to be working"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write each requirement and AND them all together.

```
nchar(PW) > 7 &&
    grepl("[a-z]", PW) &&
    grepl("[A-Z]", PW) &&
    grepl("\\d", PW) &&
    grepl("[!@#$%^&*]", PW) &&
    !grepl("(hello|123)", PW)
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between (benefit of) using && instead of & here and in general? Thanks.

Comment: @Edward The difference is explained on the help page ``help(`&`)``

Comment: Yes, _I_ know what the difference is. But it would be good if you could explain it here so others who visit here can learn. Or not.